# Does extraterrestrial refer to origin or location?

Tags: meaning

I'm listening to "Lunar Discovery" by Salvador Mercer and they detect a signal coming from the moon.  The signal is described as originating from an unknown origin, most likely **extraterrestrial**.

My first thought was "*Of course it's extraterrestrial, it's not coming from the Earth.*"  But looking at the definition it says "*not of or from the Earth*".

So what exactly is the limit of what would be considered **extraterrestrial**?

1. Would a lunar lander be considered a terrestrial source for the transmission because it came from Earth?
2. Would the transmission from a lander be considered terrestrial because the object sending it came from Earth even though the signal did not originate on Earth?
3. If we colonized another star, would signals or a ship coming from it be considered extraterrestrial?  What if hundreds of years had passed and the ship or equipment was manufactured on that planet by the colonists' descendants?
4. If a group of alien refugees landed on Earth and we let them live here, would them and their great grandchildren still be considered 'extraterrestrial' because they did not originally come from Earth?

Comment: Replace *extraterrestrial* with *Russian* or *Chinese* (or any other country/nationality) and you'll have your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition is "of or from" - so the word can have either meaning, and it depends on the context.

Astrophysicists use the word differently from how UFO conspiracy theorists use it.

For your questions:

1 & 2) The lander itself originated on earth, so it's of *terrestrial origin* or *terrestrial manufacture*.  The signals are extraterrestrial, because we need antennas that point away from the earth in order to receive them.

3 & 4) That depends very much on how our cultures develop after such a momentous process as colonizing another world.  I can't say how English-speakers 400 years from now would regard their distant cousins from another star system - they could call them anything from "earthlings in exile" to "pioneers" to "traitorous outcasts" to "extraterrestrials, no longer members of humanity".